# Update or disable built-in library sqlite3 on MacOS?

Tags: macos, svn, homebrew, sqlite

On MacOS Monterey I installed subversion with `brew install svn`.

When I do an `svn checkout` in a terminal I get:

```
svn: E200029: Couldn't perform atomic initialization
svn: E200030: SQLite compiled for 3.36.0, but running with 3.35.3
```

I tried `brew install sqlite3`, but the problem persists (probably because the system sqlite path is found first?).

`which sqlite3` gives `/usr/bin/sqlite3`
It appears that the version of the built-in sqlite3 is too old (or just different from the version `svn` is using)

Is there any way to update a built-in library, or maybe disable it, so svn uses the right version?

Comment: I highly recommend just changing your $PATH to put homebrew’s folder(s) first.

Comment: How would I do this?  this is my `/etc/paths` file : `
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
`

Comment: It's different in every shell.  I use tcsh (don't ask), you're probably using bash or zsh.  Google for that, it's out there.  If you change the contents in /etc, you might lose them after an OS upgrade.  Best to change it in your shell (in the appropriate file in your homedir).